# Unexpected CountourPlot behavior at corners

Tags: plotting

With Mma 12.0 on Win 10, I'm seeing an unexpected white line in the following `ContourPlot`.

```
ContourPlot[Min[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Similarly for `Max` or the the infinity norm.  Is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the option `Exclusions -> None`:

```
 Row[{ContourPlot[Min[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> 300],
   ContourPlot[Min[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> 300, Exclusions -> None]}]
```

[image]

Comment: So the algorithm sees the corners as jump points?  This makes sense.